# Find Value in specific row of multidimensional List

Tags: c#, matlab, multidimensional-array, find

I want to find all values (indexes) of a 3D-List in C# (`List<List<List<double>>>`), but just search in a specific region.

In matlab, this can be done by the following line:

```
find(my3DList(:,4,:) == 2)
```

This means, searching everywhere where the second dimension is set to 4. The same I want to do in C# using List. I guess the `FindAll` command could this, but I don't know how to tell the program to fix the second dimension to a specific value.

Can you help?
Thanks a lot

Comment: what will be returned by `find` function?

Comment: @Rajeev `find` should return the index of each dimension, where the value was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following

```
 var result = list.FindAll(x=>x[4].Contains(6)); // result contains matched elements not indices
```

Here 4 is fixed in second dimension, if it contains 6 it will retrieved.

**EDIT**
if you want only indices you can do as follows

```
int[] indices = list.Select((item, index) => new { x = item, i = index })
                    .Where(x => x.x[4].Contains(6))
                    .Select(x => x.i).ToArray();
```

**EDIT 2**
For fixing 3rd dimension(here 0 is fixed and 6 is matched)

```
var result = list.Where(x => x.Where(y => y[0] == 6).Count() != 0).ToList();
```

**EDIT 3**
For fixing 3rd dimension(here 0 is fixed and 6 is matched) and getting only indices

```
int[] indices = list.Select((x, i) => new { item = x, index = i })
              .Where(x => x.item.Where(y => y[0] == 6).Count() != 0)
              .Select(x=>x.index).ToArray();
```

**Example**

Following should work provided every element in the list(outer) contains 5th(index=4) element.

```
List<List<List<double>>> list = new List<List<List<double>>>()
{
    new List<List<double>>()
    {
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){6,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
    },
    new List<List<double>>()
    {
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){6,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
    },
    new List<List<double>>()
    {
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
    },
    new List<List<double>>()
    {
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){1,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,3 },
        new List<double>(){5,2,5 },
    }
};

var result = list.FindAll(x=>x[4].Contains(6));
int[] indices = list.Select((item, index) => new { x = item, i = index })
                    .Where(x => x.x[4].Contains(6))
                    .Select(x => x.i).ToArray();
```

here `result` contains only first 2 elements from original list, and indices contains matching indices(0,1).

Comment: This is great and exactly what I was looking for... Thanks!
One stupid last question: How to fix the third dimension instead of the second? --> Sorry, I'm not yet that familiar with lambda expressions

Comment: @Krus for fixing 3rd dimension you can use `var result = list.Where(x => x.Where(y => y[0] == 6).Count() != 0).ToList();`

Comment: Ok, that's really great! I actually need just the indices. So is there a possibility to at first get just the indices when the **third** dimension is fixed, and secondly to get the indices of all three dimensions in an array? For example, if the third dimension is fixed to 3, a possible return array could look like this: `{1,7,3}`.

Comment: @Krus for getting only indices, i have updated anwer, see EDIT3

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a three dimensional data structure like:

```
List<List<List<int>>> a = new List<List<List<int>>>()
            {
                new List<List<int>> {
                    new List<int>  {1,2,3},
                    new List<int> {4,5,6},
                    new List<int> {7,8,9},
                },
                new List<List<int>> {
                    new List<int> {10,11,12},
                    new List<int> {13,14,15},
                    new List<int> {16,17,18},
                }
            };
```

To limit search to a dimension in this data structure you need a helper method that flattens your list.

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> LimitToDimension(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>> list, int dimension, int index)
    {
        return (dimension == 0 ? list.Where((x, i) => i == index) : list)
            .SelectMany(secondDimension => dimension == 1 ? secondDimension.Where((x, i) => i == index) : secondDimension)
            .SelectMany(thirdDimension => dimension == 2 ? thirdDimension.Where((x, i) => i == index) : thirdDimension);
    }
```

This method takes a 3D IEnumerable, a dimension to filter and index of dimension and returns the flatten list of items in that dimension and index. For example, calling:

```
LimitToDimension(a, 1, 1);
```

returns {4, 5, 6, 13, 14, 15} and you can use 'Where' to find the element you want after that. And also you can turn this into an extension method for easier use.